# Как реализовать обязательный вызов метода базового класса?

Tags: c++, ооп

Столкнулся с интересной проблемой при написании программы на с++, есть класс родитель, есть его наследник, в наследнике я переопределяю какую-то функцию, но хочу вызвать и функцию базового класса, решение очевидное и простое

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Func()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

class B : A
{
public:
    void Func() override
    {
        A::Func();
        //aditional logic
    }
}
```

Все работает и все классно, только меня смущает дублирование кода я должен вызывать метод базового класса во всех наследниках, а что страшнее теоретически могу забыть этот вызов и будут странные ошибки. Решение тоже пришло быстро, решил сделать вот так

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Func() final
    {
        //do something
        FuncInternal();
    }
protected:
    virtual void FuncInternal() = 0;
}

class B : A
{
    void FuncInternal() override
    {
        //aditional logic
    }
}
```

Теперь всегда отработает сначала метод базового класса, потом наследника, но понял что если уровень наследования будет больше 2 то мне будет нужно вводить FuncInternal1, FuncInternal2 и т.д. И вот тут я завис, как мне решить задачу по избавлению от дублирования вызова базовой функции во всех потомках таким образом, чтоб реализация не отличалась в зависимости от количества наследников.

Думаю что я что-то упускаю из общих знаний ООП, привязка к языку не обязательна.
Спасибо

**UPDATE1**

Источник проблемы в задумке сделать абстрактный класс-интерфейс, к примеру, IRenderable, и если есть объект который наследуется от такого класса Monster : IRenderable, то я уверен что у Monster будет функция рендер и что при обращению к этой функции будет проведен некий единый набор действий описанных в IRenderable.

Comment: Ты упускаешь, что класс наследник может намеренно не вызывать базовую функцию, либо вызывать её не в начале.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш код? Вам нужно в методе наследника вызвать этот же метод базового класса?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я хочу рассмотреть именно такую ситуацию где логика базового класса обязательно нужна, а порядок выполнения может настраиваться, как во втором примере кода

Comment: @Назар, да, мне нужно вызвать метод базового класса, в функции переопределяющей базовую

Comment: @Alexei ну в c# можно написать внутри метода наследуемого класа base.Method(); и это его вызовет. В c++ вроде бы Base::Method(). На счет ситуации где логика обязательно нужна, то думаю это невозможно, а если и возможно как то выкрутить, то противоречить принципам. Наследуемый клас сам должен решать вызывать метод или нет.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, я бы попросил вас перечитать оба примера кода в вопросе, в первом случае я использую Base::Method(), и я описал почему мне такой вариант не подходит, а потом я привел второй пример кода, где сделал то что вы назвали невозможным и получил некоторые изъяны, прошу подсказать, возможно есть идеи как реализовать это по другому, или дополнить мой пример так, чтобы исправить проблему где может быть наследование более 1 раза.

Comment: Замечу в скобках, что в первом вашем варианте у вас базовый класс является конкретным, а во втором - абстрактным. Так что вы решили поставленную задачу, но решили ценой отказа от возможности создания объектов класса `A`...

Comment: @Harry, этот код написан для примера в вопросе, мы можем не делать функцию полностью абстрактной, да и в данном вопросе я хочу видеть базовый класс как интерфейс, список неких обязательных полей, свойств, функций, логик.

Comment: Тогда по вашей же логике и класс B должен быть абстрактным, если он будет унаследован. Кстати, что вы понимаете под "не делать полностью абстрактной"? Она или = 0 (независимо от наличия тела), или нет. Немножко абстрактной, как и немножко беременной, функция не бывает :)

Comment: @Harry, согласен с уточнением, я выразился неточно, спасибо. Я дописал вопрос, надеюсь UPDATE1 позволит понять суть проблемы

Comment: То, что написано в Update, вы успешно реализовали с помощью абстрактного класса!

Comment: `я должен вызывать метод базового класса во всех предках` - предках кого ? может вы имеете ввиду в потомках (дочерних классах) ?? потому как иначе это бесмысленно, у вас же один базовый класс

Comment: Мне кажется постановка задачи нарушает принцип полиморфизма, т.к. по сути навязывает классам-наследникам определенное поведение

Comment: @ampawd я имел в виду наследников, спасибо, исправил

Comment: @Alexei, а зачем метод Func делать виртуальным (чтобы потомки его перегружали) и final (чтобы потомки его не перегружали) одновременно? Если слова virtual и final убрать, получится классический невиртуальный интерфейс: в базовом классе есть невиртуальный public-метод process с телом вида { preprocess(); doProcess(); postprocess();} При этом doProcess делается виртуальным и перегружается в потомках, а preprocess и postprocess - методы базового класса, выполняющие общую для всех потомков работу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку вы пишете, что конкретный язык вам безразличен, вот вам пример с честной рефлексией на C#.

Идея: вызывать «родительскую» имплементацию не нужно, вместо этого каждый из порождённых классов может, если захочет, добавить свою имплементацию метода. Базовый метод вызывает все имплементации по очереди.

Классы выглядят при этом так:

```
class C1
{
    public void F(int x)
    {
        // вызываем в цикле все имплементации
        foreach (var impl in Util.GetAllImplementations<Action<int>>(this, "FImpl"))
            impl(x);
    }

    // имплементация в C1
    private void FImpl(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"From C1::F({x})");
}

class C2 : C1
{
    // тут нету имплементации
}

class C3 : C2
{
    // имплементация в C1
    private void FImpl(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"From C3::F({x})");
}
```

Класс-утилита (ужасы рефлексии):

```
static class Util
{
    static public IEnumerable<DT> GetAllImplementations<DT>(object obj, string name)
    {
        Type[] argTypes = GetArgTypes(typeof(DT));
        for (Type curr = obj.GetType(); curr != null; curr = curr.BaseType)
        {
            var method = curr.GetMethod(
                    name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                    null, argTypes, null);
            if (method == null)
                continue;
            yield return (DT)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(DT), obj, method);
        }
    }

    static Type[] GetArgTypes(Type delegateType)
    {
        if (delegateType == typeof(Action))
            return new Type[0];
        if (!delegateType.IsGenericType)
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected delegate type");
        var typedef = delegateType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        var isFunc = (typedef.Name.StartsWith("Func`"));
        var isAction = (typedef.Name.StartsWith("Action`"));
        if ((!isFunc && !isAction) || typedef.Namespace != "System")
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected delegate type");
        var argTypes = delegateType.GetGenericArguments();
        if (isFunc)
            Array.Resize(ref argTypes, argTypes.Length - 1);
        return argTypes;
    }
}
```

Запускаем, получаем результат:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new C3().F(1);
    }
}
```

> From C3::F(1)
>   From C1::F(1)

---

Уверен, что на C++ можно получить такой же результат при помощи какой-нибудь шаблонной магии.

Comment: Но рефлексия - это же медленно...

Comment: Какая перлесть!=) Тут нужно будет крепко погуглить, я тоже уверен что это можно реализовать в плюсах, но думал что решение будет проще. Спасибо за ответ! Даже и не знаю какой в плюсах аналог для object.BaseType

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, список делегатов можно закешировать, например, в Dictionary (most derived type -> list).

Comment: @Alexei: Я тоже не соображу сходу, а то я бы написал решение на плюсах.

Answer (score 0):

```
class One {
    public:
void Print()
{printf(" It is ONE!!!\n");
getchar();}
};

class Two : public One {
public:
void Print(){
printf("It is TWO!!!\n");
getchar();}
};

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Two Oslik;
    Oslik.Print();
    Oslik.One::Print();
}

результат:
It is TWO!!!

 It is ONE!!!
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]